# Mahout Aggregate Multiple Similarity Objects

Tags: mahout-recommender

I have 3 different types of boolean preference data that I'm using to build 3 separate similarity object. I wanted to know if it is possible to combine these 3 similarity objects into one. I have 3 separate data files, one for items followed, items messaged, and item page views. All three files are CSV files of the form `user_id, item_id`. Item `101` and `567` might have a similarity rating of `.047` based on the items followed data, but in the items messaged data the similarity could be `.10`. My question is how can I combine these to get one similarity rating between all items.